# Не могу залить скетч

Tags: arduino

Изучаю arduino (мучаю arduino nano на ATmega168P), дошел до прерывания. Залил вот такой скетч:

```
const int buttonPin = 2; 
const int ledPin =  8;

volatile int buttonState = LOW; 

void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);
  attachInterrupt(0, pin_ISR, CHANGE);
}

void loop() 
{
  Serial.print(buttonState);
}

void pin_ISR() 
{
  if (buttonState == LOW)
  {
    buttonState = HIGH;
    digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
  }
  else
  {
    buttonState = LOW;
    digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);    
  }
}
```

После заливки постоянно горит RX TX и на 8 пин всегда подается 1.3 В. Но прерывание работает, т.е. если подаю на 2 пин 5 В, то на 8 подается 5 В. В Arduino Studio могу подключится с помощью мониторинга порта, и видны значение, которые отправляет ardiuno. Но вот залить новый скетч не получается - просто висит заливка и ничего не происходит. Я спалил arduino? Что я сделал не так? Как залить пустой скетч?

Comment: Очевидно прерывание на нулевом порту как раз и мешают прошить arduino ведь в плате 0 и 1 псины как раз отвечают за сериал протокол который используется для прошивки ! Нужно отчистить чип и залить заново загрузчик ! Рекомендую делать через USB ISP программатор

Answer (score 0):

на счёт микроконтролера не переживай ты его не спалил если он работает 
может быть несолько причин 
либо ты спалил USB>TTLпереходник
либо повредил загрузчик в адуинке 
либо какой то сбой на стороне компа 
поробуй воткнуть кабельUSB в другой порт или обновит IDE ну или прошить микроконтроллер напрямую

Comment: Другие точно такие же ардуинки прошиваются без проблем, с того же компа, кабеля и порта. Попробую прошить микроконтроллер

Comment: При попытке загрузить загрузчик:
`***failed;  
avrdude: verification error, first mismatch at byte 0x0000
         0x00 != 0x3f
avrdude: verification error; content mismatch
Ошибка при записи загрузчика.`